# NSItemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:options:completionHandler: for any kind of (binary) file

Tags: ios8, ios-app-extension, uti, ios8-share-extension

I am implementing iOS Share Extension for my app, and I want to be able to get any kind of file into my app extension (e.g. a binary file of any type shared from Dropbox).

How can I achieve this behavior? `loadItemForTypeIdentifier:options:completionHandler:` expects a UTI, I've tried providing an empty string but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved my own problem. I've tried `public.data` for the UTI and it seems to work perfectly with any kind of file that I've tried.